# EntityFrameworkCore same DBContext on multiple PG Schema

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, database-schema

I would like to understand if having the same DBContext on multiple Postgres Schema is a valid architecture.

To be clear, i would like to RUN multiple instances of my application and let's the DBContext On Model Creating using a configuration parameter from the appsettings.json to segregate the data for the different application across different Schemas.

Comment: That's perfectly valid, but I'd recommend one DbContext per `database` for separation of concerns

Comment: Assuming the schemas have some commonalities, sure why not?  But if the schemas are completely different I don't see the point in doing so.

Comment: The point is....   we need to simulate a multi-tenant system on the same Database but using different Schemas...

Comment: To be clear, the database is exactly the same!  just repeated multiple time for different "end users"

Answer (score 0):

edit

Ok, let me improve my answer  (remembering that I did this to meet two distinct databases in the same application, in your case it will be the same database)

if you are trying to connect with a different user in the same database to access only what the user can access you will have to put different connection strings
so you should use something to identify which one to use, in my case I use a variable in my settings file, like this:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{

    #region ..:: Fields ::..

    private static readonly string DataBaseContext = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataBaseContext"];

    #endregion

    #region ..:: Construtor ::..

    public MyDbContext()
        : base(DataBaseContext)
    {
        //Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }

    #endregion

    ..........

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
    {
        ........
    }

}
```

now `OnModelCreating` example

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    #region ..:: Definições ::..

    var tipoBancoDados = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TipoBancoDados"];
    var mySchema = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mySchema"];

    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(tipoBancoDados.Contains("PostgreSql") ? "public" : "dbo");
    //modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(mySchema);

    #endregion


    .....
}
```

It works for me when choosing which type of database to use, PostgreSql or SqlServer

Your `DataBaseContext` variable must contain the name of the connection to be used, according to your requirements

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="PgSqlAdmin" connectionString="SERVER=X.X.X.X;UID=postgres;PWD=PGPASSOWRD;PORT=5432;DATABASE=mydatabase;" providerName="Npgsql" />
    <add name="PgSqlUserA" connectionString="SERVER=X.X.X.X;UID=UserA;PWD=PGPASSOWRD;PORT=5432;DATABASE=mydatabase;" providerName="Npgsql" />
    <add name="RemoteDb" connectionString="Data Source=X.X.X.X;Initial Catalog=MyDataBase;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=sa;Password=SqlServerPassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

see that I put two entries for PostgreSql in the strings of connections one for the postgres user and one for UserA

I do not know if this solves your problem, but it sure works to choose between PostgreSql and SqlServer in the same application, simply inform the app.Config (or Web.Config) which connection will be used and which type of data

```
<appSettings>
    <!--Usar: PostgreSql | SqlServer -->
    <add key="TipoBancoDados" value="PostgreSql" />
    <add key="DataBaseContext" value="PgSqlAdmin" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: mhmm no this is not what i've asked!  Thanks anyway for the answer!